# Logarithmic question

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

In the following question I fail to understand why the A option is correct.

I understand that D is wrong, and that B and C are correct, but why is A correct?

If $3^x=4^{x-1}$, then $x $cannot be equal to:

A. $2\log_32$

B. $\frac{2}{2-\log_23}$

C. $\frac{1}{1-log_43}$

D. $\frac{2\log_23}{2\log_23-1}$

By taking $\log_3$ on both sides, we get $x=2(x-1)\log_32$.

After that we get B and C as correct after making modifications but how do we know that A is correct?

Comment: A is not correct!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x=2\log_3{2}
\\ 3^{2\log_3{2}}=4^{2\log_3{2}-1}
\\ 2^2=\frac{4^{2\log_3{2}}}{4}
\\ 16 \neq 16^{\log_3{2}}$$
Therefore the expression cannot equal A.